# Python Structures

Tags: python, ctypes

I am try to convert a C Structure to Python using Ctypes.

The Structure I am trying to convert is :

```
typedef struct LibraryInfo
    {
        uint32_t    size;                                // Size of the structure
        char        libName[MAX_LIBRARY_NAME+1];                        // Library name
        char        provider[MAX_LIBRARY_PROVIDER_NAME+1];                  // Provider
        uint32_t    version;                                                    // Library version, i.e: 0x01030005 --> v.01.03.0005  
    } LibraryInfo;
```

The equivalent Python Code is:

```
class LibraryInfo(Structure):  
    _fields_=[("size",c_uint),  
              ("libName",c_char * MAX_LIBRARY_NAME ),  
              ("provider",c_char * MAX_LIBRARY_PROVIDER_NAME),  
              ("version",c_uint)]
```

The functions which takes this structure as argument is `resCode = QueryLibraryInfo(&libraryInfo);`

The error I am getting is `invalid parameters passed`.
This is a library function call.
I am using this in python                                                   HPDRLGL_MAX_LIBRARY_NAME=200   HPDRLGL_MAX_LIBRARY_PROVIDER_NAME=200      class HPDRLGL_LibraryInfo(Structure): *fields*=[("size",c_uint), ("libName",c_char *(HPDRLGL_MAX_LIBRARY_NAME+1)), ("provider",c_char * (HPDRLGL_MAX_LIBRARY_PROVIDER_NAME+1)), ("version",c_uint)]      Still I am getting the same error, INVALID PARAMETERS . I have passes a pointer to the structure as you said .

Comment: Thats not an issue. I have made the size same as passed in C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the function signature, it seems that you need to pass a pointer to the structure:

```
libraryInfo = LibraryInfo()
resCode = QueryLibraryInfo(byref(libraryInfo))
```

And you should really keep the `+ 1` in your structure definition.

Comment: I am using this in python     HPDRLGL_MAX_LIBRARY_NAME=200  
HPDRLGL_MAX_LIBRARY_PROVIDER_NAME=200  
class HPDRLGL_LibraryInfo(Structure):  
        _fields_=[("size",c_uint),  
                  ("libName",c_char *(HPDRLGL_MAX_LIBRARY_NAME+1)),  
                  ("provider",c_char *   (HPDRLGL_MAX_LIBRARY_PROVIDER_NAME+1)),  
                  ("version",c_uint)]      Still I am getting the same error, INVALID PARAMETERS . I have passes a pointer to the structure as you said .

Comment: @Ashish Gupta: Please do not post code in comments.  Please **update** your question with the correct code.

Comment: I have edited the question. Can you suggest some solution to the above problem.